# Probability of 9 tails

Tags: probability

An experiment is performed to flip a fair coin 10 times and observe the outcome of each flip: heads (labeled 'H') or tails (labeled  'T'). For instance, one outcome, written as a 10-tuple, might be (H,T,T,T,T,T,T,H,H,H).

How many total outcomes are there for this experiment? Explain your reasoning.

There are 1024 different outcomes. You are flipping a (single, 1) fair coin which has 2 sides (heads and tails) so the Sample Space (N(S)) = 1024, 10 consecutive flips, with 2 sides = 2^10=1024 - is this part correct?

How many ways can the result of the experiment show exactly nine tails? Explain your reasoning.

I was thinking that there are 113 different possibilities for have 9 tails? I did 1024/9? Can you help me?

Comment: First part is correct. Why are you dividing 1024 by 9? 

Maybe you could approach problem by listing down some 10-tuples with 9 tails; see a particular pattern in it?

Comment: I dare you to show even 13 different ways to get 9 tails ....

Comment: Would a matrix work? or just a standard table?

Comment: You don't need anything as complicated as a matrix. Just start listing the possible outcomes with nine tails. For instance: (H,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T).

Comment: So there is only 10 possible ways. but how do I show this mathematically? is there an equation?

Comment: Listing them is a perfectly valid solution. To show it "mathematically" rather than listing all ten, you could observe that if there are nine tails, then there must be one head, and the head can appear in one of $10$ positions. If the question were more complex, e.g., "how many outcomes have exactly seven tails?", then you might be interested in [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: Thanks. I displayed them in a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking of it this way:  Each head is a "success" and each tail is a "failure."  You have ten slots to fill, one for each flip, each of which is either a success or failure.  How many ways can you fill ten slots such that exactly one of them is a success?

Hint: have you studied [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)?